# SVG Polyline make Y points larger

Tags: svg, polyline

Is there anyway to make the Y points on SVG larger. My Y points are on decimal gap. When you look it on browser it will just look like a straight line.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 100" class="chart">    
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="#0074d9" stroke-width="1"
      points="
        0,55.15
        110,55.43
        220,55.98
        330,56.01
        440,56.09
  "/>  
</svg>
```

Cheers!

1st Pic. Current when you run the svg in browser
[image]

2nd Pic. What Im trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: I'm unclear about your goal here. A polyline is expected to show just that - a line. So what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Im trying to create a simple graph.

Comment: You say you want to "make points larger". Is that the vertices within that line? Maybe you can sketch your desired output somehow.

Comment: sure, I will create one. thanks

Comment: The gap between lines are just decimal. If you run it, it will just look like a straight line. What I want to achieve is to show the ups and downs on the polyline like a graph line. Im still creating the  sketch

Comment: the y co-ordinates don't change by much, therefore what you see is pretty much a straight line. Why didn't you expect it to be a straight line? What is a "decimal gap"?

Comment: As you can see the Y points gap is just on decimal. 55.15, 55.43 so the Y points will not reflect that much, it will just look like a straight line.

Comment: @Sirko I have already added a sketch

Comment: Are you creating that chart manually or are you using some library? [d3js](https://d3js.org/) for example offers way to set min/max for the scale. So if your scale just uses the range of say 54 - 56, you'll have something close to your desired output.

Comment: Im trying to create it manually since, it will be shown on a tooltip on a particular value. Having it on a library will make the site load very slow.

Comment: Ok, than you'll have to do the scale-transformation yourself. Basically you're mapping an input domain to an output range. So the input may be [54,56], while the output might be [0, 100]. In a simple case you choose a linear function to transfer between both intervals mapping each value of the domain to a value in the range.

Comment: Can you point me to any documents regarding about your suggestion or maybe an example. Thanks

Comment: Change the viewBox values so they don't run from 0 to 100 in the y axis but are more appropriate for your data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well - here's a solution that assumes a few things:

- You want the y coordinates in your SVG to match your original data. If you want this, then you have to flip your drawing surface afterwards, because the 0,0 origin in SVG is top, left, not bottom, left as in most charts.
- You don't care about indicating absolute scale and just want to indicate relative changes no matter how minor, and you don't care about the relative scale of X and Y axis.

So, this adds a CSS transform that flips your line vertically, shrinks the viewBox so that the y axis is zoomed into the mid-fifties. And then squashes the resulting drawing into the drawing space by using preserveAspectRatio/meet (I didn't bother redoing your X axis, I just shrunk it to 10% by moving the decimal place.)

```css
#tooltip-flip{
  background: #DDD;
  transform-origin: 50%, 50%;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<svg id="tooltip-flip" viewBox="-0.25 54.7 4.8 1" width="500px" height="200px" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">    
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="#0074d9" stroke-width="0.005"
      points="0,55.15 1.10,55.43 2.20,55.98 3.30,56.01 4.40,56.09"/>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks michael!