# How to exaggerate the Y axis of an SVG plot?

Tags: math, svg, plot, charts, polyline

In this SVG chart, the line is too flat.  How can I exaggerate the difference in Y values of the points so that it appears more "zig-zaggy", with the lowest point of the line at the bottom of the graph and the highest point at the top?

```css
svg {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% + 4em);
  transform: translateX(-2em);
  clip-path: polygon(2em 0, calc(100% - 2em) 0, calc(100% - 2em) 100%, 2em 100%);
}

polyline {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -100 900 100" class="chart" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw;">
          <defs>
            <marker id="red-circle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" orient="auto">
              <circle fill="red" cx="5" cy="5" r="5" />
            </marker>
          </defs>
          <polyline fill="#FEF9CC" stroke="#FED225" stroke-width="2" points="
              0, 0
              100, 23
              200, 21
              300, 20
              400, 20
              500, 23
              600, 28
              700, 30
              800, 30
              900, 30
              0, -99999
              0, 0
             " marker-start="url(#red-circle)" marker-end="url(#red-circle)" marker-mid="url(#red-circle)" />
        </svg>
```

Comment: adjust the viewBox values - makes the height value smaller.

Comment: Changing the 2nd and 4th values of `viewBox` don't appear to have any effect on the "zig-zaggyness", I tried `50` `-50` and `200` `-200`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the formula [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/askmath/comments/lxi8hn/how_to_exaggerate_the_y_axis_of_a_graph/) on Reddit.  Here is how I implemented it:

```js
const exaggerate = function () {
  const polyline = document.querySelector('polyline');
  const points = [...polyline.points].slice(2, -2);
  // slice off (ignore) first 2 and last 2 because
  // they are purely for closing the loop
  // so that it can be filled with a color
  const ys = points.map(({ y }) => y);
  const y_min = Math.min(...ys);
  const y_max = Math.max(...ys);
  points.forEach((point) => {
    point.y = (point.y - y_min) * 100 / (y_max - y_min);
  });
}

exaggerate();
```

```css
svg {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% + 4em);
  transform: translateX(-2em);
  clip-path: polygon(2em 0, calc(100% - 2em) 0, calc(100% - 2em) 100%, 2em 100%);
}

polyline {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -100 900 100" class="chart" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw;">
          <defs>
            <marker id="red-circle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" orient="auto">
              <circle fill="red" cx="5" cy="5" r="5" />
            </marker>
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66473797/how-to-exaggerate-the-y-axis-of-an-svg-plot#      </defs>
          <polyline fill="#FEF9CC" stroke="#FED225" stroke-width="2" points="
              0, 0
              100, 23
              200, 21
              300, 20
              400, 20
              500, 23
              600, 28
              700, 30
              800, 30
              900, 30
              0, -99999
              0, 0
             " marker-start="url(#red-circle)" marker-end="url(#red-circle)" marker-mid="url(#red-circle)" />
        </svg>
```

**EDIT:**

Came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185223/svg-polyline-make-y-points-larger) question and answer as well, for anyone interested.